# configure entitydatasource with entity set that includes multiple tables

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, entity-framework-5

I have an entity data model with two entities.  One entity called Posts contains blog posts and another entity called Comment contains comments.  I set up the association as a one to many relationship and the primary keys are both postid in both Posts and Comment.

However, when I try to bind this to an entitydatasource control it only lets me select either the Posts or the Comment entity set not both.  What I want to do is to be able to bind the post with its comments to the data source, but I can't seem to figure out a way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you use include property of entitydatasource? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488550(v=vs.100).aspx